# How to block IE from caching 301 redirects

Tags: internet-explorer

I use ATT as an internet provider and a "service" they "provide" is that any page that fails to resolve in DNS is redirected to [**this**](http://dnserrorassist.att.net/search/?q=http%3A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%3Fq%3Dhttp%253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%253Fq%253Dhttp%25253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%25253Fq%25253Dhttp%2525253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%2525253Fq%2525253Dhttp%252525253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%252525253Fq%252525253Dhttp%25252525253A//mywebsite.com/%2525252526r%252525253D%2525252526t%252525253D0%25252526r%2525253Dhttp%252525253A//mywebsite.com/%25252526t%2525253D0%252526r%25253Dhttp%2525253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%2525253Fq%2525253Dhttp%252525253A//mywebsite.com/%25252526r%2525253D%25252526t%2525253D0%252526t%25253D0%2526r%253Dhttp%25253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%25253Fq%25253Dhttp%2525253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%2525253Fq%2525253Dhttp%252525253A//mywebsite.com/%25252526r%2525253D%25252526t%2525253D0%252526r%25253Dhttp%2525253A//mywebsite.com/%252526t%25253D0%2526t%253D0%26r%3Dhttp%253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%253Fq%253Dhttp%25253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%25253Fq%25253Dhttp%2525253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%2525253Fq%2525253Dhttp%252525253A//mywebsite.com/%25252526r%2525253D%25252526t%2525253D0%252526r%25253Dhttp%2525253A//mywebsite.com/%252526t%25253D0%2526r%253Dhttp%25253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%25253Fq%25253Dhttp%2525253A//mywebsite.com/%252526r%25253D%252526t%25253D0%2526t%253D0%26t%3D0&r=http%3A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%3Fq%3Dhttp%253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%253Fq%253Dhttp%25253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%25253Fq%25253Dhttp%2525253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%2525253Fq%2525253Dhttp%252525253A//mywebsite.com/%25252526r%2525253D%25252526t%2525253D0%252526r%25253Dhttp%2525253A//mywebsite.com/%252526t%25253D0%2526r%253Dhttp%25253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%25253Fq%25253Dhttp%2525253A//mywebsite.com/%252526r%25253D%252526t%25253D0%2526t%253D0%26r%3Dhttp%253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%253Fq%253Dhttp%25) fun url (a snippet here: http://dnserrorassist.att.net/search/?q=http%3A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/%3Fq%3Dhttp%253A//dnserrorassist.att.net/search/ ...). those of you with a keen eye might see something wrong with it... It is supposed to be just a <strike>google</strike> att search for the web address you typed. unfortunately it seems to recursively search itself

Once you are redirected the first time, IE caches the result and will only send you to that URL, bypassing the original website, meaning you can't get back there once the dns issue is resolved unless you manually clear your internet cache.

Is there a way to block IE from caching these redirects at all on the client side? even better if it only blocks redirects to *.att.net

Comment: Can you provide a picture rather than a "fun" url? That way people might actually look at it ;)

Comment: Why not change to a DNS provider (like Google, Level3, or OpenDNS) that doesn't violate the standards, instead of just hacking around the issues that their stupidity causes?

Comment: added a bit of the url to the question, the full thing is 1000+ characters though. The place I'm being redirected to isn't as important as how to block this in general. http://dnserrorassist.att.net/search/$websitename is probably the intended target

Comment: @joseph forcing dns causes issues with switching between corporate and public internet (I run into this a lot trying to get to a private intranet site). It's just as difficult to set dns servers every time I switch as it is to manually clear my cache :(

Comment: You could do it on your home router instead of on your computer, so you wouldn't have to do anything extra when you switch to your corporate LAN

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea, and probably what I'll end up doing at home. I am still curious about the original question for if you were at a school/hotel and they were doing stupid dns things